# What does PMID stands for?

Tags: integrated-circuit, battery-charging, charger, charging

there are pins on TI BQ25619 charger named PMID and PMID_GOOD. what does PMID actually stands for?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it say on the data sheet?

Comment: It is part of the boost mode output control section of the IC. This another one of the great undefined acronyms.  I have no clue what it stands for. Good Luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *what does PMID actually stands for?*

It stands for "power-middle" as per [this explanation](https://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management-group/power-management/f/power-management-forum/857942/bq24195-bq24195-and-all-other-ics-that-have-pmid-pin) from TI: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Andy aka